# Chrome 36.0.1985.143 ignore imported webfont after document is ready

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, webfonts

Every since chrome latest update (36.0.1985.143) on Mac, 
a few seconds after the document is ready - Chrome selectively "ignores" the custom imported webfont on my website (Memofish.com) and restores is to default.

Needless to say, I did not make any changes on my website and this issue began after restarting my Mac, while Chrome updated to version 36.0.1985.143.

How can I report this issue? 
Anyone else experienced this problem and know any workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can report the issue using this instructions:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en

or here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list